# Convert Sql all operator to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm in need of retrieving details from a table which should be excluded from another table output.
The following query successfully retrieved the required output:

```
select * from "table1" 
where 
"table1"."Id" != All (select "table2"."table1Id" from "table2" where (*conditions*))
AND *conditions*
```

I want the same query in linq. I tried and cannot able to achieve it as i dont know how to use **all** in linq.

```
from table1 in _db.table1
where
table1.Id != (from table2 in _db.table2 where (*conditions*))
&& *conditions*
select new class() {
                      Id = user.Id,
                      Name = user.Name
                  };
```

I have tried out many references but does not worked for me. Assist me in converting this sql statement to linq.

Comment: genuine question: you have SQL that works and does what you want; why do you *want* to convert it to LINQ? *at best*, that just adds layers and indirections to get exactly the same result - but more likely: you'll end up with a less optimal version of the SQL, and uglified C#...

Comment: Can you briefly tell me ,what you want to achieve with the given query?

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = _db.table1
 .Where(t1 => conditions)
 .Where(t1 => _db.table2.Where(t2 => conditions).All(t2 => t1.Id != t2.table1Id));
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe using contains:

```
from table1 in _context.table1
where
!(from table2 in _context.table2 where (*conditions*) select table2.table1Id).Contains(table1.Id)
&& *conditions*
select new class() {
                  Id = user.Id,
                  Name = user.Name
              };
```